# Points in 3D space

Tags: geometry

I have a problem with points in 3D space:

I have three points, A, B, and C.

I know the x, y, and z coordinates of A and C.

I know that the y coordinate of B is (y coord. of A + y coord. of C) / 2

I know that the z coordinate of B is (z coord. of A + z coord. of C) / 2

How do I find the x coordinate of B?

More context:

I'm making a quadrupedal robot. Focusing on one leg, it has 3 points: a hip, knee, and foot. The position of the foot is fixed (105, -111.44, 52.5). The position of the hip is set by the angle of rotation that I input in each of the three axes ( (105, 0, 52.5) when there is no rotation). The position of the knee is determined by the other two positions. The line connecting the hip to knee and knee to foot MUST be 78.8 (since you can't extend the length of the robot's parts; they are fixed). I know that the y and z position of the knee is the midpoint of the line connecting the hip to the foot. I want to know how to work out the x coordinate of the knee, given all the other coordinates. See photos for more info  [photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/louDR.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Are the points collinear?

Comment: No. For example: A(105,0,52.5)  B(x, -55.72, 52.5)  C(105, -111.44, 52.5)

Comment: Not enough information is provided. There is nothing constraining the _x_ coordinate of **B** to be a specific value. Can you please provide more context and/or details here?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines given the lengths of the sides, you can backsolve for the flex angle. then find the height from the line and that might help.

Comment: In the absence of other information, the locus of point $B$ is the set of points $(t,y_B,z_B)$ where $t$ is free, i.e., it is a line.